# Better way to design database for online assesment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I am working on Online Exam module, initially i have created the database and it's work fine when the number of questions are fixed, in my case i have 10 Questions and multiple users,now the requirement is different i want to conduct exam of 50 questions so what should i do or any time an admin can change the number of question as per the requirement

```
CREATE TABLE `test_sheet` (
`user_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`q1` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q2` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q3` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q4` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q5` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q6` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q7` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q8` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q9` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`q10` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Not Available',
`score` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`start_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`random_question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`passedTime` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`remainTime` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_update_time` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now test_sheet table like this

```
insert  into `test_sheet`(`user_id`,`q1`,`q2`,`q3`,`q4`,`q5`,`q6`,`q7`,`q8`,`q9`,`q10`,`ip_address`,`score`,`start_time`,`random_question`,`passedTime`,`remainTime`,`last_update_time`) values ('demo@123',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'Not Available',0,'2016-06-11 14:46:52','1,5,4,2,3,10,9,7,6,8','59','5258','2016-06-11 14:47:25');
```

i have an alternate option like this

```
User_ID   ||  Q_ID    ||  ANS_ID 
demo@123  ||    1     ||   4
demo@123  ||    2     ||   3
demo@123  ||    3     ||   2
demo@123  ||    4     ||   4
demo@123  ||    5     ||   1
Xyzz@123  ||    1     ||   2
Xyzz@123  ||    2     ||   4
Xyzz@123  ||    3     ||   2
Xyzz@123  ||    4     ||   1
Xyzz@123  ||    5     ||   3
```

now i have 50 or more questions and user for exam May be 300 so the rows will be approx 15000 or more so what is the better way or any other idea

Comment: you should create a separate table for the questions, like your alternate option. Then you are not limited by the number of questions of an exam.

Comment: See normalization first.

Comment: I have separate table for questions and the columns are question,qid,op1, op2,op3,op4,correct_op,no_per_question.. the above table is use when the exam is started and maintain for quick answer if any user want to check the previous question which is attempted or electricity has gone during the exam so i am storing each qid,userid and the selected option on each attempted question...

Comment: You should almost never have numbered columns like that; it is a code smell which in this case means you should add another table (especially since they're nullable). As they say, "design for 0, 1 or infinity."

Comment: @TimLehner i have done mistake, i have to woke up when i was implementing it but the mistake is mistake, i am ready to change in my existing application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "alternate option" is perfect. You use a second table for the answers:
ExamID, UserID, QuestionID, AnswerID. ExamID is important, if one user can fill a test-sheet with the same questions again.

Later you can extend it with some other informations, like answer-duration, etc.

I would make two tables to store the results (maybe is the syntax not korrekt, I usualy use MS-SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE test_sheet
    (
    test_id int NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(100) NULL,
    score int NULL,
    start_time timestamp NULL,
    passed_time int,
    remain_time int,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (test_id)
    )

CREATE TABLE test_sheet_answer
    (
    test_id int NOT NULL,
    question_id int NOT NULL,
    question_order int NOT NULL,
    answer_id int NULL,
    answer_duration int DEFAULT(0),
    PRIMARY KEY(test_id, question_id)
    )
```

Edited: use the test_sheet_answer table to store the random order of the questions. At the start, you can fill the table with empty rows with the random order. If the question is not answered yet, store in answer_id NULL or 0.

Comment: Should i separate the score, answer_duration, ip_address and random_question on different table

Comment: what is random_question?

Comment: it's comma separated values which is used to store all the question with random sequence and it will be used when the exam terminate abnormally like power cut or system shutdown so i store the random sequence on the time of start the exam...!

Comment: Why PRIMARY KEY(test_id, question_id) ?

Comment: because one test-process has more than one answers. So the PK consists of "which test-process and which question".